# Calculate Robust CI's for Stratified-Cox Regression Interaction

Tags: confidence-interval, interaction, cox-model

I have a multivariable stratified cox regression model with correction for correlation with [Robust SE](https://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/biostat-58pdf/doc-10027288). There is [interaction by the stratified variable](https://rkbookreviews.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/summary-survivalanalysis-a-self-learning-text.pdf), and so I would like to report ***adjusted*** Hazard Ratios with CIs for this interaction. Below is an example:

```
library(survival)
data("kidney")

age_cuts <- quantile(kidney$age, probs = c(.33, .66))
kidney$agegroup <- cut(kidney$age, breaks = c(-Inf, age_cuts, Inf), labels = c('t1', 't2', 't3'))
kidney$age2 <- ifelse(kidney$agegroup=='t2', 1, 0)
kidney$age3 <- ifelse(kidney$agegroup=='t3', 1, 0)
kidney$disease2 <- ifelse(kidney$disease %in% c('PKD', 'Other'), 1, 0)

mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(agegroup) + disease2 + 
             disease2:age2 + disease2:age3 + frail + cluster(id), 
             data = kidney)
summary(mod)
                 coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se      z Pr(>|z|)
disease2      -0.2028    0.8165   0.5625    0.3891 -0.521    0.602
frail          1.4463    4.2473   0.2720    0.2500  5.786 7.22e-09
disease2:age2 -0.6402    0.5272   0.7904    0.5612 -1.141    0.254
disease2:age3 -1.3371    0.2626   0.8380    0.8968 -1.491    0.136

disease2         
frail         ***
disease2:age2    
disease2:age3    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

              exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
disease2         0.8165     1.2248   0.38085     1.750
frail            4.2473     0.2354   2.60215     6.933
disease2:age2    0.5272     1.8968   0.17550     1.584
disease2:age3    0.2626     3.8081   0.04528     1.523
```

The exponentiated coefficient for 'disease2' (with CIs from Robust SE) would be the Hazard Ratio for disease within the first age category: HR 0.82 (0.38-1.75).

For age categories 2 and 3, the HRs would be exponentiated coefficients *disease2 + disease2:age2* and *disease2 + disease2:age3*, respectively. But how could I calculate the robust SE for this linear combination in order to report CIs? Is there a way to use the model vcov?

I'm aware of the [emmeans package](https://mran.microsoft.com/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html), but it's unclear how it handles interaction with a stratified term or robust SEs. So it might be ideal to calculate manually.

(EDIT)...would it be?

```
terms <- names(mod$means)
vcov <- mod$var
var <- diag(vcov)
names(var) <- terms
dimnames(vcov) <- list(terms, terms)
sqrt(var["disease2"] + var["disease2:age2"] + 2*vcov["disease2", "disease2:age2"])
sqrt(var["disease2"] + var["disease2:age3"] + 2*vcov["disease2", "disease2:age3"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, the model code shown does not produce the summary that is shown. I obtained your summary after removing the term `cluster(id)` and putting it in a separate argument:

```
mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(agegroup) + disease2 + 
             disease2:age2 + disease2:age3 + frail, cluster = id,
             data = kidney)
```

That point resolved, let's examine the SEs obtained via the `vcov()` function:

```
> sqrt(diag(vcov(mod)))
     disease2         frail disease2:age2 disease2:age3 
    0.3890715     0.2499800     0.5611917     0.8967877
```

and note that these are the same as what is labeled "robust se" in the summary.

Accordingly, we can obtain the needed estimates via:

```
> L <- data.frame(age1=c(1,0,0,0), age2 = c(1,0,1,0), age3 = c(1,0,0,1))
> bhat <- coef(mod)
> sapply(L, function(x) sum(x * bhat))
      age1       age2       age3 
-0.2027748 -0.8429491 -1.5399127
```

and their (robust) SEs via:

```
> V <- vcov(mod)
> sapply(L, function(x) sqrt(t(x) %*% V %*% x))
     age1      age2      age3 
0.3890715 0.3940111 0.8462397
```

The **emmeans** support for `coxph` objects does not seem to work right when there is a `strata` term in the model. However, you can manually construct the needed `emmGrid` object using the model estimates, plus the `L` matrix created above:

```
> library("emmeans")
> emm <- emmobj(bhat = coef(mod), V = vcov(mod), 
+     levels = c("a1","a2","a3"), linfct = t(as.matrix(L)), 
+     df = Inf, tran = "log")

> summary(emm)
 level estimate    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 a1      -0.203 0.389 Inf    -0.965    0.5598
 a2      -0.843 0.394 Inf    -1.615   -0.0707
 a3      -1.540 0.846 Inf    -3.199    0.1187

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> ### exponentiated results
> summary(emm, type = "response")
 level response    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 a1       0.816 0.318 Inf    0.3809     1.750
 a2       0.430 0.170 Inf    0.1989     0.932
 a3       0.214 0.181 Inf    0.0408     1.126

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Note that the CIs for age 1 match those for `disease2` in the outputs in the summary.

### Update

I have repaired the support for `coxph` models in **emmeans** so that it can handle a `strata()` term (previously those types of models were not supported). The updated code will be in versions *after* 1.4.5, and are available from the github site (see the DESCRIPTION).

Here is how it works out for this example. First, create the `agegroup` and `disease2` variables as in the question. (`disease2` is a binary variable, and it acts like a factor in `emmeans()`.) Fit this model:

```
mod2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(agegroup) * disease2 +
              frail + cluster(id), data = kidney)
```

You can verify that the summary of `mod2` is virtually identical to what is shown in the OP. The `emmeans()` function predicts log hazard for all combinations of `agegroup` and `disease2`:

```
> emm <- emmeans(mod2, ~ disease2 | agegroup)
> emm
agegroup = t1:
 disease2 emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
        0  1.713 0.296 Inf    1.1325      2.29
        1  1.510 0.448 Inf    0.6327      2.39

agegroup = t2:
 disease2 emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
        0  1.713 0.296 Inf    1.1325      2.29
        1  0.870 0.475 Inf   -0.0618      1.80

agegroup = t3:
 disease2 emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
        0  1.713 0.296 Inf    1.1325      2.29
        1  0.173 0.729 Inf   -1.2555      1.60

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

To get log hazard ratios, use comparisons of those:

```
> prs <- pairs(emm, reverse = TRUE)
> confint(prs, by = NULL)
 contrast agegroup estimate    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1 - 0    t1         -0.203 0.389 Inf    -0.965    0.5598
 1 - 0    t2         -0.843 0.394 Inf    -1.615   -0.0707
 1 - 0    t3         -1.540 0.846 Inf    -3.199    0.1187

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

(Summarizing with `by = NULL` just makes for a more compact display.)

To get the hazard ratios themselves, back-transform:

```
> confint(prs, by = NULL, type = "response")
 contrast agegroup ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1 / 0    t1       0.816 0.318 Inf    0.3809     1.750
 1 / 0    t2       0.430 0.170 Inf    0.1989     0.932
 1 / 0    t3       0.214 0.181 Inf    0.0408     1.126

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```